# How to write a call or method as a regular expression in my Java code?

Tags: java, regex

My Homework Problem:
Create a class named Lease with fields that hold an apartment tenant’s name, apartment number, monthly rent amount, and term of the lease in months. Include a constructor that initializes the name to “XXX”, the apartment number to 0, the rent to 1000, and the term to 12. Also, include methods to get and set each of the fields. Include a nonstatic method named addPetFee() that adds $10 to the monthly rent value and calls a static method named explainPetPolicy() that explains the pet fee as follows: A pet fee of $10 is added to the monthly rent.

Create a class named TestLease whose main() method declares four Lease objects. Call a getData() method three times. Within the method, prompt a user for values for each field for a Lease, and return a Lease object to the main() method where it is assigned to one of main()’s Lease objects. Do not prompt the user for values for the fourth Lease object, but let it continue to hold the default values. Then, in main(), pass one of the Lease objects to the showValues() method that displays the data. Then call the addPetFee() method using the passed Lease object and confirm that the fee explanation statement is displayed. Next, call the showValues() method for the Lease object again and confirm that the pet fee has been added to the rent. Finally, call the showValues() method with each of the other three objects; confirm that two holds the values you supplied as input and one holds the constructor default values.

I completed the coding for both classes, and it all works great!  Unfortunatley, I received an error message.  I need help with this one error message.  Maybe, someone can help me understand.

My code and its error message are below:

```
   ''' getData(leaseOne);
    '''getData(leaseTwo);
    '''getData(leaseThree);


  '''  public static Lease getData(Lease l){

  '''      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  '''      System.out.println("Enter Tenant's Name: ");
   '''     String name = input.nextLine();
   '''     l.setName(name);

    '''    System.out.println("Enter Apartment Number: ");
    '''    int aptNumber = input.nextInt();
    '''    l.setAptNumber(aptNumber);

    '''    System.out.println("Enter Amount of Rent: ");
    '''    double rent = input.nextDouble();            
    '''    l.setRent(rent);

     '''   System.out.println("Enter Term of Lease: ");
     '''   int term = input.nextInt();
     '''   l.setTerm(term);

     '''   return l;
  '''  }
```

Here is what the homework grading system explained to me:

Code PatternIncomplete
TestLease contains calls for getData

Description
Searched your code for a specific pattern:

getData(backslash symbol here)((backslash symbol here));

I now understand that it wants me to write the getData(); call as or with a regular expression, but I don't understand how.  I included the call to the method and the method in my code example.  I read and read about regular expressions.  I am struggling with it.  Please help me understand how to write the getData(); call as a regular expression, according to my code.

I already created everything else as the instructions ask.  Everything else passed.

Comment: AFAIU, slash symbol is just a part of regex pattern. What I would try is to make your `getData` method non-`static` and then maybe without parameters (i.e do not pass `Lease` object as an argument there, use it as `this` when the method will be non-`static`.

Comment: Re-read once more and am pretty much sure now that the error message says that auto-checking system searches for non-argument calls, i.e. `getData()`, not `getData(leaseOne)`.

Comment: I believe my confusion comes from the difference of calling a method versus passing an object to a method.  I changed my call to actually call the method, instead of passing the object.  I am still getting errors that it is not recognizing the method getData().  It is the same with calling the showValues() method, within my instructions.  I made it non-static, and "this" is already used in the Lease class.  I am still getting errors, but will continue to review.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What the problem is

The error message says that it is seaching for literally `getData()` calls, i.e. method calls without arguments.
Your calls contain `Lease` argument, eg `getData(leaseOne)`.

### What are those strange backslashes in `getData\(\)`?

The backslashes are just put there to escape the `(`, which is a special symbol for regexp patterns. So the regexp just searches for `getData()` string, `\` just escapes to search `(` symbol as is.

### How to fix

You have to make your `getData()` method take no arguments.

Now the method is `static` and takes `Lease` object as an argument.
My suggestion is to make it instance method (i.e. non-`static`), so that it can access `Lease` object methods as methods of `this`.

Answer (score 2):

The grading system is reporting to you that your code does not have any lines that match the `getData\(\)` [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).  It kind of implies that with the words “specific pattern,” but I fault the grading system for failing to mention the worlds “regular expression” in that message.

In regular expressions, parentheses are special characters with special meaning. For the pattern to match an actual parenthesis character, the pattern must take steps to protect or “escape” that character.  The most common way to do this is by preceding a special character with a backslash, which acts as an escape character—meaning, it indicates that the following character should be treated as a literal character, ignoring any special meaning it might normally have.

So `getData\(\)` is a regular expression that matches any occurrence of "getData()" in whatever text it is applied to (in this case, your code).

Note that a “forward slash” leans to the right (`/`) while a “backslash” leans to the left (`\`).  A backslash is a special character in regular expressions, while a forward slash is not (at least in Java;  some other languages use it as a delimiter).

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty clear I think. Your assignment specifically wants you to "Call a getData() method three times."

Your university grading system did not find three calls to getData().

The issue here is that you've written getData(Lease l) and called it thrice, but you should have created getData(), which creates 'new Lease' inside and returns 'Lease' object instead.

So you would have to write something like

```
public static Lease getData(){
    Lease l = new Lease();
    // Whatever code
    return l;
}
```

Call the above method thrice instead.